# Image getting too big and becomes scrollable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<section class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="headingGroup" class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block mt-5">
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/4000x500.svg" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

I've attached a video of the issue I'm facing over here

https://vimeo.com/595765873

Comment: use `col-6` instead of `col-lg-6`

Comment: @HarshitRastogi but at smaller breakpoints, i need my image to span across the entire screen but not so much that it gets extremely zoomed out like shown in the video

Comment: then try adding `max-width` and `max-height` to `100%`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `col-6` instead of `col-lg-6`, so, everything works fine now.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<section class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div id="headingGroup" class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block mt-5">
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/4000x500.svg" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```